# How to refer to the last overlay of slides without overlay specifications?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, labels, overlays

By default, `\ref{slidelable}` refer to the first page of the labeled slide. The author wants to change the default to be referring to the end page of the slide. Since the author uses overlays `<+>` very often, calculating and assigning overlay specification to `\label<lastoverlay>{slidelable}` is a lot of work. Here are two possible approaches:

1. Replace the default label overlay specification from `<1>` to `<\insertframeendpage-\insertframestartpage+1>`
2. Patch `\ref` command to jump to the end page of the slide.(I haven't figured how to do this yet.)

My code for the first approach:

```
\g@addto@macro\beamer@lastminutepatches{%
  \let\beamer@origlabel\label
  \def\label{\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@label}{%
    \expandafter\beamer@label\expandafter<\insertframeendpage-\insertframestartpage+1>}}

  \let\beamer@origlabel@in@display\label@in@display
  \def\label@in@display{\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@label@in@display}{%
    \expandafter\beamer@label@in@display\expandafter<\insertframeendpage-\insertframestartpage+1>}}
}
```

The problem of the first approach is when I reduce the number of overlays a slide has, say from 6 to 4, the last page of the slide duplicates extra two times (i.e, 1,2,3,4,4,4) since the label is still on overlay <6>. I need to delete the .aux files to prevent this problem every time before I compile the edited slides.

Any suggestions for these two approaches? Or is there any other ways to refer to the last page of the slide without overlay specification?